# does docpad secondary url redirect feature work?

Tags: url, docpad

Based on the documentation of docpad [primary url](http://docpad.org/docs/meta-data#-url-), all requests to a document secondary url should be redirected to the primary url. But actually it respond the expected page directly when requesting any secondary urls without any redirection.

For example, you have a docpad document `/src/documents/secondary-url.html.md` like:

```
---
urls:
 - '/my-secondary-urls1'
 - '/my-secondary-urls2'
---

# primary url should be `secondary-url.html`
```

Then run command `$ docpad run`

It will responds status 200 when hitting either `http://localhost:9778/my-secondary-urls1` or `http://localhost:9778/my-secondary-urls2`. While expected result is a redirect with status code 301 to `http://localhost:9778/secondary-url.html`

It seems an expected feature if checking [this line](https://github.com/bevry/docpad/blob/572fad61f699e20d0f0516c3e362d4cd7e20270d/src/lib/docpad.coffee#L4619) of docpad code.

I'm curious if this is a defect or a deprecated feature?

BTW: I have a simple fix here which won't become a pull request until I read the contribution guide: https://github.com/shawnzhu/docpad/commit/731cdec43f9d9d155c8a8310494575d9746a065c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was addressed in [issue 850](https://github.com/docpad/docpad/issues/850) of project docpad, and fixed in [pull request 905](https://github.com/docpad/docpad/issues/905), so further version than v6.70.1 of docpad will contain this fix.